# why should the past perfect be used?

Tags: past-perfect

I did my homework and met an offer.

```
He felt tired because he had worked a lot.
```

why I have to use 'had' if I can say that:

```
He felt tired because he worked a lot.
```

Comment: You don't have to. Either is fine. It just depends on what you're trying to say.

Comment: Okay. What is the difference with using “had” and without it?

Comment: I would use these differently as follows: "He felt tired because he had worked a lot" could mean e.g. he worked 80 (or whatever) hours in the last 2 weeks so now he's tired. "He felt tired because he worked a lot" would mean something more like he works lots of hours every week, on a sort of 'ongoing' basis.

Comment: His working a lot is anterior to his feeling tired, so the past perfect is appropriate..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both sentences are grammatical, but they are typically interpreted differently.

> He felt tired because he **had** worked a lot.

This means that he was tired because of a *particular* event in the past. It's referring to a certain incident, or span of time, that made him tired. (Generally in contrast to him not being tired.)

> He felt tired because he worked a lot.

This means that he was generally tired because he had a *habit* of working a lot. It's something that occurred regularly. Rather than being tired on a specific day after pulling an all-nighter, for instance (where the addition of *had* is more appropriate), he always worked a lot and was always tired.

---

Which tense you use is determined by which of those senses you are trying to convey.